# use the "Deflate()" compression algorithm with the DataCompression extension (Swift)

Tags: swift, saml, deflate

I am looking to use the "Deflate()" compression algorithm with the "DataCompress" extension to compress and possibly decompress a variable containing SAML, to then return a "String" type variable and display it in a "TextView ".

I aim to code an SSO for a mobile application on iOS.
When I try to manipulate this algorithm, I have problems converting the "Data" type variables to "optional".

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance ! :)

**ViewController:**

```
let sourceData = """ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit mi nibh ornare proin blandit diam ridiculus, faucibus mus dui eu vehicula nam donec dictumst sed vivamus bibendum aliquet efficitur. Felis imperdiet sodales dictum morbi vivamus augue dis duis aliquet velit ullamcorper porttitor, lobortis dapibus hac purus aliquam natoque iaculis blandit montes nunc pretium. """.data(using: .utf8)!

let samlDeflate = SamlDeflate(samlDE:sourceData)

TVRequestDeflate.text = samlDeflate
```

**Class Deflater:**

```
import Foundation
import DataCompression

func SamlDeflate(samlDE: Data) -> String {
    let res = samlDE.deflate()
    let decompressedString = String(data: res!,encoding: .utf8)

    print(samlDE,res,decompressedString)
    return decompressedString!
}
```

Comment: "deflate" means compress. "_inflate_" means decompress.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer, but I really wanted to do a "deflate()" and not an "inflate()".

However I found the solution to my problem in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I reply to my own post to indicate the answer found in the meantime.
Thanks.

**Class Deflater**

```
func SamlDeflate(samlDE: Data) -> String {
    
    let resDE = samlDE.deflate()
    let opDeflated : String? = resDE?.base64EncodedString()
    var res : String = ""
    
    if let text = opDeflated {
        res = (text)
    } else {
        res = "One or more of the optionals don’t contain a value"
    }
    
    return res
}
```